# How to provide FLOATING_POINT support in android-ndk-r7b-linux while compiling Speex?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, speex

I am trying to Compile Speex for Android using android-NDK, currently I am targetting android 2.3.3 however later I will have to test my app on all the android versions greater than 1.6. My Android.mk file looks like:-

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libspeex
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DFLOATING_POINT -DUSE_KISS_FFT -DEXPORT="" -UHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
./libspeex/bits.c \
./libspeex/buffer.c \
./libspeex/cb_search.c \
./libspeex/exc_10_16_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_10_32_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_20_32_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_5_256_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_5_64_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_8_128_table.c \
./libspeex/fftwrap.c \
./libspeex/filterbank.c \
./libspeex/filters.c \
./libspeex/gain_table.c \
./libspeex/gain_table_lbr.c \
./libspeex/hexc_10_32_table.c \
./libspeex/hexc_table.c \
./libspeex/high_lsp_tables.c \
./libspeex/jitter.c \
./libspeex/kiss_fft.c \
./libspeex/kiss_fftr.c \
./libspeex/lpc.c \
./libspeex/lsp.c \
./libspeex/lsp_tables_nb.c \
./libspeex/ltp.c \
./libspeex/mdf.c \
./libspeex/modes.c \
./libspeex/modes_wb.c \
./libspeex/nb_celp.c \
./libspeex/preprocess.c \
./libspeex/quant_lsp.c \
./libspeex/resample.c \
./libspeex/sb_celp.c \
./libspeex/scal.c \
./libspeex/smallft.c \
./libspeex/speex.c \
./libspeex/speex_callbacks.c \
./libspeex/speex_header.c \
./libspeex/stereo.c \
./libspeex/vbr.c \
./libspeex/vq.c \
./libspeex/window.c \
./ native.c \


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem is at some point of my code I require **FLOATING_POINT** configuration, however the code only works if I change it to FIXED_POINT otherwise the threads don't get CPU cycles  as they should(the one thread eats most of the CPU cycles i.e. the program hangs in the floating arithmetic inside that thread) How I can make FLOATING_POINT work for me ?

Comment: what's the problem with floating point? I've compiled libspeex with standalone ndk (with float)

Comment: Encoder Thread eats all the time.... and Decoder Thread doesn't get time

Comment: try adding `-mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp` to `CFLAGS` or options for armv7 and/or neon

Comment: Tried everything but nothing worked so I started working with FIXED_POINT configuration, It is at least working good so far...